# Complex curved background for an Android view

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

I want to make a multi-layered background with the gray layer being on top of the red one so that it can be movable up and down the y-scale. My issue is with the way I can achieve the complex curve that is on the top of the gray layer.

Any ideas where can I look for solution for my problem?

Comment: is the curve animating?

Comment: @sso.techie No, it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a collapsing toolbar like this : [Collapsing Toolbar Layout Guide](https://antonioleiva.com/collapsing-toolbar-layout/)

and set the background gray, and the "giraffe" image (look in the link) as the picture you put in your question.

Comment: My issue is not with the way I can move the different layers but with the way I can set the complex curve on the top of the gray layer.

Comment: Why do you need the curve on top? I don't understand what are you trying to accomplish..

Comment: That's the design I have from my designer.

Comment: I still don't understand why the curve needs to be on top, if it's only design then it's meaningless. If your designer will add shadow to the curve it won't solve the problem?

Comment: You can use `FrameLayout` and add the two Images. One image is the gray backgound and the other one is the red with the curve (your designer should give you the red with curve image). If your `minSdkVersion` is 21 or higher you can also set `elevation`.